# How to add or append value in array in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I create a string array in class?

Also I have to add or append values to that array.

I can use Firebase real-time database to store array values in database.

Not to a specific key.

I declared array as:

```
private string[] uiddata;
```

That array is useed in a for loop and add elements to the array as

```
public void Click()
{
    _uid = int.Parse(_uidText.text);

    for(int i = 0; i < uiddata.Length;i++)
    {
        uiddata.Add(_uid);

        //_score = int.Parse(_scoreText.text);

        _uidRef.SetValueAsync(_uid);
        //_scoreRef.SetValueAsync(_score);

        _uidRef.RunTransaction(data =>
        {
            data.Value =_uid ;
            return TransactionResult.Success(data);
        }).ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception != null)
                Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        });
    }
}
```

In the script above I try to add my value in the array but gives this error:

> error CS1061: Type `string[]` does not contain a definition for `Add` and no extension method `Add` of type `string[]` could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Answer (score 7):

Since you are using C#, you should check this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/

Exactly this part:

> The number of dimensions and the length of each **dimension** are
>   established when the array instance is created. These values **can't be
>   changed during the lifetime** of the instance.

So it means you can define a size at the beginning, for example 5, and then you can add values to the array like follow:

```
String[] numbers = new String[5];
numbers[0] = "hello1";
numbers[1] = "hello2";
numbers[2] = "hello3";
numbers[3] = "hello4";
numbers[4] = "hello5";
```

or

```
 String[] words = new String[] {"hello1", "hello2", "hello3", "hello4", "hello5" };
```

But if you try to add an extra element to this array you will have an exception

```
numbers[5] = 111111; //Exception here
```

But if you need append values, you can use [collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of arrays. For example a List:

```
List<String> myList = new List<String>();
myList.Add("Value1");
myList.Add("Value2");
...
```

Comment: You can not, the unity engine use other programming language, as I see in your case it is c#, and as I explained you it is not possible. You need to use list. Try to use ArrayList as I say in the example, and there you can use the method .Add("value") to add elements when you need.

Comment: So check the last part of my answer, and declare uiddata as an ArrayList, not as an Array